# Apache Beam - PCollection<Object[]> to PCollection<Object>

Tags: java, apache-beam, dataflow

I have a Json file, and the content it's an array of object per line, it's possible to convert a PCollection of Object[], to PCollection of Object ?

```
PCollection<String> events = 
        p.apply(TextIO.read()
                .from("C:\\data\\*.zip")
                .withCompression(Compression.ZIP));


PCollection<User[]> objectsArray = events.apply(ParseJsons.of(User[].class))
        .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(User[].class));


PCollection<User> object = objectsArray.apply( ????? );
```

Comment: You could use `ParDo` to read every line, and then build a custom function to parse each (comma delimited?) line.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i got it. I Changed the ParseJsons line to a ParDo: 
´PCollection<User> jsonEvents = events.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, User>() {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @ProcessElement
 public void processElement(@Element String element, OutputReceiver<User> receiver) {
  User[] userArray = new Gson().fromJson(element, User[].class);
  for (User user : userArray) {
   receiver.output(user);
  }
 }
}));´